# Missing html markup in Joomla template file

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to add some code to a Joomla site just before the  tag. I have never used Joomla before but from what I read up it should be something like this -

- Log on to: http://www.yoursite.com/administrator/
- In the top menu select: "Extensions" > "Template Manager"
- Now select the template which is marked as default and click "Edit"
- In the template edit page click "Edit HTML"

Or index.php file from your template folder however when I do both of these options the only thing there is:

```
<?php
if (class_exists('T3Template')) {
    $tmpl = T3Template::getInstance($this);
    $tmpl->render();
    return;
} else {
    //Need to install or enable JAT3 Plugin
    echo JText::_('Missing jat3 framework plugin');
}
```

Any ideas where I can find the normal HTML markup with the  tag?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You won't be able to edit that template via Joomla backend. You have to track the code of the template, see where is `render` method defined and how it works, and you will be able to find where is html defined.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean or how can I go about finding out where the render method defined?

Comment: I think with the T3 framework, they come from a plugin. not entirely sure though

Answer (score 0):

The markup for your template would normally be in /templates/template_name/index.php but your joomlart template uses a framework (which is not standard joomla, but common practice amongst large template providers).  You should look into joomlart documentation, so you can make sure you will follow their best practices.  From a quick glance at their forums, try looking at the \plugins\system\jat3\jat3\base-themes\default\page\default.php file (see here: http://www.joomlart.com/forums/showthread.php?55256-Add-code-before-lt-body-gt-amp-lt-head-gt&highlight=template+edit+jat3)

In a standard Joomla template, you would find the code inside abovementioned index.php.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the template files at following location:
*Your_Base_URL/templates/mynewtemplate/*